# How to handle incoming files via Apache Mina SSHD SFTP Client in Java

Tags: java, sftp, apache-mina, apache-sshd

I want to listen any updates of the file system but on the client-side. I know that I can do the same thing on server-side via SftpEventListener but I'm not sure if there is any option to implement this on the client-side via the aforementioned listener or somehow else.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to upload/download files using apache SSHD ScpClient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62692515/how-to-upload-download-files-using-apache-sshd-scpclient)

Comment: @MartinZeitler, Probably not I think. In the fact I have to specify some actions on client-side as reaction to the changes on server-side file system. For example if I could read  any file that could appears in the server's file system by client.

Comment: @Sandro700 could you find any solution for this?